# JtR with Excel 2013

Tags: password-cracking, kali-linux

I need to recover a PW for an Excel 2013 workbook. I am using Kali. When I try to run the workbook or any individual tab through Office2John, I get "Invalid OLE file".  So I renamed to .zip, extracted files, and found the hash value and salt value in the XML.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get JtR to read this information so that I can recover the password.  Am I missing something simple?  Is there a specific format I need to create in the hash.txt file for JtR to read?  Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to convert the hash into a format that the password-cracking suite is expecting.

The best collection of such tools is from the John the Ripper project, and the one that is probably what you're looking for is [office2john](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/office2john.py).

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment makes it hard to improve my answer. Unless there's context that's not included in the question, my answer above is indeed exactly how you would extract a JtR-ready hash.